# Embedding the new google map in your website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I just found out that the new google map doesn't have a link button that used to let people get the embed code which they can embed in their websites.

[LINK-1](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72644) 
   [LINK-2](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/websitemaps.html) (both links say 'click on "link" option to get the embed code')

Also,
They seem to have changed the url format,(a lot cleaner now!)
Now it looks like:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview?ie=UTF8#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d2020!2d74.995161!3d13.2164639
```

where the !data parameter holds all the information(lat,long,zoom,screen span etc.,)

```
!data=!1m4!1m3!1d2020!2d74.995161!3d13.2164639
```

So I tried constructing the map's embed parameters manually(assuming that !2d74.995161 and !3d13.2164639 represent lat and long)

```
<iframe class="map" width="924" height="208" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=74.995161,13.2164639&amp;spn=0.003381,0.017231&amp;z=16&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

But to my surprise the above embed code is pointing to an entirely different location(Greenland Sea! where as my original link is of IND).

My QUESTION: How to get the embed code in google's new map.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the latitude and longitude reversed:

Try this,

`https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=13.2164639,74.995161&spn=0.003381,0.017231&z=16&output=embed`

**code snippet:**

```html
<iframe class="map" width="924" height="208" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=13.2164639,74.995161&spn=0.003381,0.017231&z=16&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the new Google maps they added a "Share and embed map" option.

It's hidden in the little gear icon down on the right side of the map.

Or you can manually build it...but this is easier and it will also link to a company's Google listing.

Comment: Yes, now they have the share option, but at that time it wasn't present which made me post this question.

Answer (score -2):

Just figured out how to elliminate that pesky toolbar and other toolbars so I can see the map full screen.  Was actually lookng on here to figure out how to do it, but none of the suggested solutions worked.  I figured it out by accident actually.

Here is what I did.  Go to the map.  Holding down the ctrl key and using the wheel on the mouse roll to make everything smaller.  Now if you do this while the pointer is hovering over the toolbar, those toolbars get smaller.  Now move the cursor to the map and roll the other way.  You can zoom in on the map and those toolbars will remain their tiny size.  Love this, yeah overtonmath "u know the sin 30?"